# Keyboard shortcut in Jupyter notebook to select suggestions from the drop down menu

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

In my regular workflow with Jupyter Notebook running in my browser, I like how get 'tab suggestions' for completion. But I have to always use the down arrow key or the mouse if the entry is not the first one. I don't know if it's common knowledge or not but I have not been able to figure it out.

[image]

Is there a keyboard shortcut that when I press tab key, and then I can simply jump to the third option in the picture?

Comment: Why not simply type the third letter so `async` becomes the first entry?

Comment: @glhr of course, but what if the class names are long like `authentication_prameters` and imagine having four variables in the scope starting with `authentication`

Comment: The closest I've found is using the Page Up & Page Down keys to go to the first or last element in the drop-down.